# How to navigate to a directory in C:\ with Cygwin?

Tags: cygwin

I'm trying to install [PyQt4](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download) so I can mess around with it. The installation guide said I had to install [Sip](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/sip/download). The last step to [installing Sip](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/sip4/installation.html#building) is to use the `make install` command. Windows doesn't have that, so I looked it up and everything I saw said to install Cygwin. So I did. But...sip is in `C:\Python31\sip`.

Can I run this from the Cygwin command? If so, how would I do that?

Or can I run this from the normal windows command prompt?  If so, how would I go about that?

Answer (score 830, accepted):

Use:

```
cd /cygdrive/c
```

Comment: You may also use
`cd c:/`

Comment: and make sure there is no space in and after `/cygdrive/c`

Answer (score 213):

I'll add something that helps me out a lot with cygwin.  Whenever setting up a new system, I always do this

```
ln -s /cygdrive/c /c
```

This creates a [symbolic link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ln_(Unix)#Specification) to `/cygdrive/c` with a new file called `/c` (in the home directory)

Then you can do this in your shell

```
cd /c/Foo
cd /c/
```

Very handy.

Comment: Note that this prevents you from having files/directories named `c` with the ability of referencing them normally.

Comment: I recently installed MSYS2 and this was the default behavior, with `/cygdrive` in-fact not working...

Answer (score 142):

`cd c:` is supported now in cygwin

Comment: Valid for `cd e:` and prompt will be `/cygdrive/e`

Answer (score 55):

You already accepted an answer, but I just thought I'd mention that the following also works in Cygwin:

```
cd "C:\Foo"
```

I think the `cd /cygdrive/c` method is better, but sometimes it's useful to know that you can do this too.

Answer (score 12):

You can just use

```
cd C:/Users/../..
```

Answer (score 6):

As you'll probably want to do this often, add aliases into your .bashrc file, like:

```
alias cdc='cd /cygdrive/c'
alias cdp='cd /cygdrive/p'
```

Then you can just type on the command line:

```
cdc
```

Answer (score 3):

Define a variable in .bashrc :

```
export C=/cygdrive/c
```

then you can use

```
cd $C/
```

and the tab autocompletes correctly (please include the / at the end)

Answer (score 2):

On a related note, you may also like:

```
shopt -s autocd
```

This allows you to cd a dir by just typing in the dir

```
[user@host ~]$ /cygdrive/d
cd /cygdrive/d
[user@host /cygdrive/d]$
```

To make is persistent you should add it to your `~/.bashrc`

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

```
/cygdrive/c/directoryname
```

Answer (score 1):

The one I like is:  `cd C:`

To have linux like feel then do:

```
ln -s /cygdrive/c/folder ~/folder
```

and use this like: `~/folder/..`

Answer (score 1):

`$cd C:\`

`>` (Press enter when you see this line)

You are now in the C drive.

Comment: The `>` is because the backslash at the end of the line escaped the newline...

Answer (score 0):

Create a file named "overrideBashCdForWindowsPaths" in your HOME folder. Paste the following lines into that file and save it:

```
#!/bin/bash

function cd() {
    CD_PATH="$(history | tail -1 | sed -e "s,.*${FUNCNAME[0]}\s*,,g")"

    if [ -z "${CD_PATH}" -o "${CD_PATH}" = "~" ]; then
        CD_PATH="${HOME}"
    fi

    builtin cd "$(cygpath "$CD_PATH")"
}
```

Next, type the following command in a terminal, while you are in your HOME folder:

```
echo ". overrideBashCdForWindowsPaths" >> .bashrc
```

Close your terminal and open a new one. You can now easily change into that Windows folder by simply typing

```
cd C:\Python31\sip
```

The script reads the last command, extracts the path and passes it to Cygwin's path-conversion tool. By naming the function "cd" we sort of 'override' Bash's builtin "cd" and delegate the actual call to it in the very last line.

Comment: Thanks @KoenigGunther, it works! But a little bit slow though for changing directory. Is there a way to make it faster just like using quote? e.g. `cd "C:\Python31\sip"`

Answer (score 0):

Something that is worth mentioning here is that Cygwin's `cygpath`, still does not handle spaced Windows paths properly, especially in Bash scripts running under Cygwin. The trick is to understand how `Cygwin` interprets quotes in Bash scripts.

The following does **not** work:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
TBDIR="/cygdrive/c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/MyDir/"

if [ -d "${TBDIR}" ]; then 
    echo "Found MyDir directory at: ${TBDIR}"
    cd "$TBDIR"
else 
    echo "MyDir program directory not found!"
    echo "Wrong DIR path: ${TBDIR}"
    exit 1
fi
```

But this does work:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
# Cygwin-ism: No quotes!
TBDIR=/cygdrive/c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/MyDir/

if [ -d "${TBDIR}" ]; then 
...
```

As far as I know, there is currently no known workaround using `cygpath`, that can properly handle spaces in the bash scripting context but you can use quotes in your scripts.