# identify.exe: IncompatibleAPI

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

### 1. Summary

I want to apply torn edge effect to my images in ImageMagick. I find [**bordereffects script**](http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/bordereffects/index.php), but I can not run it in my Windows.

---

### 2. Expected behavior

Like [**script description**](http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/bordereffects/index.php).

---

### 3. Actual behavior

```bash
SashaChernykh@DESKTOP-EEOT0TN /cygdrive/d/Test
$ bordereffects SashaMagic.png Test.png
identify.exe: IncompatibleAPI `./bordereffects_A_1372.mpc' @ error/mpc.c/ReadMPCImage/772.
```

---

### 4. Settings

I have file `SashaMagic.png` in folder `D:/Test`.

---

### 5. Steps to reproduce

I install [**ImageMagick**](https://chocolatey.org/packages/imagemagick) and [**Cygwin**](https://chocolatey.org/packages/cyg-get) → I download `bordereffects` script → I add folder with `bordereffects` file in my PATH user environment variable → I [**change `convert` to `magick`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38319795/5951529) in `bordereffects` file → I open Cygwin64 terminal →[**`cd d:Test`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15673422/5951529) → I run command `bordereffects SashaMagic.png Test.png` → I get actual behavior.

---

### 6. Environment

**Operating system and version:**
Windows 10 Enterprise LTSB 64-bit EN
**ImageMagick:**
ImageMagick 7.0.4-3 Q16 x64 2017-01-07
**cyg-get:**
1.2.1

Comment: Try changing `identify` in the script to `magick identify`, or reinstall **ImageMagick** but this time, be sure to check the box `Install **legacy** commands`.

Comment: @MarkSetchell: thanks! I change `identify` to `magick identify` and I get output. But I get [**another errors**](https://www.pastery.net/cxrvku/). [**Expected output image**](http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/bordereffects/images/hatching_white_s5_d5_c5_p2.jpg), [**actual output image**](http://i.imgur.com/ONYVqfu.jpg). Thanks.

Comment: Edit the script, and at the end of the very first line, add a space followed by `-xv`. Run it again and you'll get lots of debug output to read and check....

Comment: @MarkSetchell: [**OK**](https://www.pastery.net/ugvvmh/). But I don't understand, how can I find an errors... Thanks.

Comment: I guess your cygwin thing is missing `bc` maybe - try running `bc -v`.

Comment: I have to go out for a few hours. If you do not have `bc`, try commenting out lines 188,189, 198, 199, 216, 217 by putting a `#` as the first character on each of those lines

Comment: @MarkSetchell: at first I install [**bc for windows**](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/bc.htm), and I get errors. But if I install bc use [**cyg-get**](https://chocolatey.org/packages/cyg-get), now I get expected behavior and don't get error. Please, move your comments to answer, that I can raise your reputation. Thanks.

Comment: @MarkSetchell: I'm sorry, why I need to use `magick identify`, but not `identify`? I run in terminal command `where identify` — I get only `D:\Chocolatey\bin\identify.exe` — path to ImageMagick file. I don't have other programs with `identify` command. Thanks.