# Missing folders in Cygwin64 terminal

Tags: shell, directory, cygwin

I just installed Cygwin64 to run a Makefile on Windows but I don't have any of my  windows folders present on Cygwin64.

I don't know if it's because of the package but I just pick the "Make" package from the setting menu.

Any clues of how to found and open my folder with it ?

It doesn't solve my issue because I can now access to my folders but I got the following error warning :

$ make build
cp ~/.ssh/id_rsa build_sources/id_rsa
cp: impossible d'évaluer '/home/a.pasina/.ssh/id_rsa': No such file or directory
make: *** [Makefile:5: build] Error 1

I think that it would be a path issue, do you know why ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to navigate to a directory in C:\ with Cygwin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1850920/how-to-navigate-to-a-directory-in-c-with-cygwin)

Comment: how you build or installed your `id_rsa` ?