# How can I install sip(4.19.19) for pyqt4?

Tags: python, pyqt, python-sip

I'm sorry to ask such a question... I want to install sip4(4.19.19) for PyQt4 in windows 10. But

I've already found this articles

[How to navigate to a directory in C:\ with Cygwin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1850920/how-to-navigate-to-a-directory-in-c-with-cygwin)

https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/pipermail/pyqt/2010-February/025937.html

https://pypi.org/project/sip/4.19/

but i can't figure it out what's wrong. As you know, pyqt4 can't use 'pip install' or

'make, make install' it in linux. so I have to install it by CMD.

Many article says Download from https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/sip/download

and unzip the file (e.g. `C:/sip-4.19.19`)

setting path in CMD(e.g. `cd C:/sip-4.19.19`)

and install it.    (`python configure.py`)

I've already checked where packages installed(`C:\Users\~\AppData\Local\Packages\~\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages`) there is no sip-4.19.19inst

and i got a message from vs code

```
File "c:/Users/~~/Drill3.py", line 6, in <module>
    from PyQt4.QtCore import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sip'
```

How can I handle this problem? Thanks for reading.

Comment: If you want to execute the following steps: 1) `python configure.py` 2) `make` and 3) `make install` although for this you must have a compiler installed as a visual studio that can be tedious. The simplest is to use what this answer indicates: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22651895/6622587

Comment: On the other hand you should use pyqt5: `pip install pyqt5` since pyqt4 is deprecated years ago.

Comment: Thanks for answering immediately! I'll try it.